# Alamofire not generating network lost/timeout error in multipart upload

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

```
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15.0
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 15.0
    self.alamofireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)


self.alamofireManager.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 1)!, withName: "file", fileName: "image.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        if let parameters = params{
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
            }
        }
    }, to:apiURL, method: .post, headers: authHeader)
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                DDLogInfo("Image Upload Progress : \(progress)")
            })
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                //print response.result
            }
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut || error._code == NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost {
                print("Time Out/Connection Lost Error")
            }
            DDLogInfo("Error :\(error.localizedDescription)")
            break
        }
    }
```

Here I am utilising the default session behaviour but still not getting any error for either timeout OR network connection lost.

I am disconnection the internet connection after I start request but no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I responded on GitHub, this is due to your confusion over the `result` in the trailing closure. This is the result of the multipart encoding, not the network request. To get the network request status you would check in the `responseJSON` you're using on `upload`.